# weird characters in database

Tags: php

hi i need to store the weird character in my database but when i am trying to do so the weird character is replace with unknown character.  i am giving you one example when i am try to enter in Sönke Wortmann in database it is stored as SÃ¶nke Wortmann. i want to store above text as same as it was.please tell me how can i do so

Comment: `SÃ¶nke` is what you see when the UTF-8 encoded string of `Sönke` is interpreted with [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Because in UTF-8 the character `ö` (U+00F6) is encoded with 0xC3B6 that represents the two characters `Ã` (0xC3) and `¶` (0xB6) in ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Unicode tables as well as a Unicode connection to your database.

**Assuming you use MySQL:**

Set the default character set of your table to utf8 and make sure the connection to your database is also using this character set:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Check the character set of your current connection with:

```
echo mysql_client_encoding($conn);
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php

When creating your tables do something like this:

```
create table tableName (
    // Your table definition
) default charset = UTF8
```

If you have done these things and add weird characters to your table, you will see it is displayed correct.